# Stored Procedure stops if "SELECT fieldname INTO var" returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, percona

I'm running a stored procedure and have ran into a problem with the following line:

```
SELECT photo_data_id 
  INTO gallery_rel_id_check 
  FROM photo_data 
 WHERE object_type = 4 
   AND data_id = 0 
   AND photo_id = row_photo_id LIMIT 1;
```

In some cases, this query will return 0 rows and thus gallery_rel_id_check doesn't get a value assigned to it.

For some odd reason, this seems to stop the stored procedure. Should I be assigning gallery_rel_id_check in a different way as I need to use it later in the procudure to check to see if its > 0

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `LIMIT 0, 1;`?

Comment: Do you need to know the value of `photo_data_id`? If not, just do a `COUNT(*)` query instead. Otherwise you have to catch the error.

Comment: You can also do `SET gallery_rel_id_check = (select ...);`

Comment: @Paulo, that did the trick, stick that in an answer and i'll mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credit goes to @Paolo Bergantino

Just use:

SET gallery_rel_id_check = (SELECT...);

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a continue handler to explicitly set gallery_rel_id_check to the appropriate value if the query does not return any rows.

For example:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET gallery_rel_id_check = -1;
```